# Turn a file into a tuple (Python 3.6)

Tags: python

I'm working on a program that can read any sort of file, and edit it. I've written most of the program, but I can't figure out how to open a file in a certain way.

What I need is a piece of code that takes a file and returns a large tuple for manipulation.  Now, I know this has been done before, but this needs to open it in *binary*, preferably as a tuple of ints ranging from 0-255.

**For example:**
A file that contains:

`testing`

*should not* return

`("t","e","s","t","i","n","g")`

it should return:

`(116, 101, 115, 116, 105, 110, 103)`

(the ASCII encoding for "testing")

I'm sure this can be done, but i'm having troubles with getting Python to agree. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

*Edit: I was *not* expecting a reply in 30 seconds

Comment: `tuple(open(fname, 'rb').read())`

Answer (score 1):

Just open in `rb` (read bytes) mode, call the `read()` method and convert to a `tuple`:

```
>>> tuple(open('f.txt', 'rb').read())
(116, 101, 115, 116, 105, 110, 103, 10)
```

where the content of `f.txt` is `"testing"`.

---

*Note that we get a `10` as this is the code for a new line. If this is not desired, then you can just slice it off: `tuple(open('f.txt', 'rb').read()[:-1])`.*

Answer (score 0):

Just use [ord()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#ord) like this:

```
with open('some_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    result = tuple(ord(c) for c in tuple(f.read()))
```

**Output:**

```
>>> with open('some_file.txt') as f:  # some_file.txt contains 'testing'
...   print(tuple(ord(c) for c in f.read()))
...
(116, 101, 115, 116, 105, 110, 103)
```

Answer (score 0):

`ord()` gives the ASCII code.
Read the whole file, iterate over each charter and and convert it:

```
tuple(ord(x) for x in open(file_name).read())
```

Example

File content of `testing.txt`:

```
testing
```

Now:

```
>>> tuple(ord(x) for x in open('testing.txt').read())
(116, 101, 115, 116, 105, 110, 103)
```

Version for multi-line file stripping the newline charterers (as well as leading an trailing whitespace).

File content of `testing.txt`:

```
testing
testing
```

Code:

```
>>> with open('testing.txt') as fobj:
...     res = tuple(ord(x) for line in fobj for x in line.strip())
>>> res
```

(116, 101, 115, 116, 105, 110, 103, 116, 101, 115, 116, 105, 110, 103)